# Django: Searching with __icontains Across All Fields Produces Duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model called Books(models.Model) that has a variety of fields including author, title, and year created. I want to filter this list across all fields of the Book model. For example, if I search for "Winnie," I want all Book instances with "Winnie" in the title, author, or year created to come up, but do NOT want to same instance of a model to come up. For instance, if "Winnie" is in the title AND author of a specific instance, I only want that instance to appear once.

I have tried using the following code to accomplish this:

```
books = Books.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_query) | Q(author__icontains=search_query) | Q(year_created__icontains(search_query)).order_by("author")
```

where search_query is a variable that represents the search query.

However, I am getting duplicate results as explained earlier. How do I prevent these duplicate results?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: use `books = Books.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_query) | Q(author__icontains=search_query) | Q(year_created__icontains(search_query)).distinct().order_by("author")
`

Comment: Does it matter if I put .distinct() before or after .order_by("author")

Comment: significantly 'No'